# Can't show the vertical ticks lines on Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am trying to set up the vertical lines- extending the ticks on the X axis. What I do is to

```
 axisX:
 {
   categoricalValues: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
   plotStripColor: 'red',
   plotStripDashStyle: 'ShortDashDot'
 },
```

I need the lines to be red andhave picked up the 'ShortDashDot' style which isn't quite important. I cannot make the lines to appear, althoug i used the Solid and the other values. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is to set the lines thickness, using the plotStripWidth property. Giving a color is not enough, since by default the line is not only white, but has a 0 thickness.

```
axisX: {
   plotStripColor: 'red',
   plotStripDashStyle: 'ShortDashDot',
   plotStripWidth: 2
}
```